# Answers not always sorted by votes

Tags: support

Has something recently changed that allows answers with lower scores to end up higher up than answers with higher scores?

[image]

I think I've seen this a number of times now in the past few weeks, and the above image is an example I've taken a screenshot of.

Neither post is accepted, and neither answer was written by the same user who wrote [the question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95402/45266).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or something was changed recently, or it's always been this way and the situation is causing this. I hope I'm not overlooking something obvious...

Another example: [image]

**Welp. Per comments below, I was overlooking something obvious., Thanks, User Doktor Mayhem.**

Comment: Have you checked what sorting option you have enabled? on the right above the answers...

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Oh dang. Well now I feel silly. Just changed it back to votes. Thank you! Should I delete this then, or leave it for the community?

Comment: Could close it I guess. I think this is already covered on meta.se